# regarding google visualisation api for geo chart

Tags: api, visualization

I am using this code for making a geo chart and  I am getting the country and popularity on mouse over ,
I want to display additional fields or string along with these values but in new line next to them..for example
Country : India
Popularity :100
Value:200
Share:100

How can I achieve this ? please help regarding this.

```
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);
```

just go thorough this link

http://jsfiddle.net/SCjm8/44/

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart